# Signal converter

Tags: pcb, signal-processing

Any suggestion how to achieve the function in the below picture. Its a signal converter for my car ignition. The switched ground is normally used to the coil, but I wish to feed the signal to a ignition module that only takes a 3V to 1V PWM signal. [image]

Comment: You write "input signal 12 V" but show "switched ground." Does this mean that you have a 12 V vehicle supply (which is really more than that) and a switched ground signal? Or does it mean something more complex than that I might not entirely gather from your diagram?

Comment: Honstly I am no big elektrichian, that why a sak in the forum and I might use some “wrong” terms. The grounded switch in intended to go to the negative coil. Meaning each time in closes (switched ground) it makes the ignition coil spark. But I wish to have this controlled be a Bosch ignition module, but this module in intended for at 3 to1 Volt signal. When the it goes from 3 to 1V the Bosch module fires.
So I am trying to use the  use this “switched ground” to achieve this 3-1V signal. Does it make sense ?

Comment: Yes. Put into my words I think you are completely replacing the ignition coil and condenser, leaving the breaker points (switch) available for use with a ***new*** Bosch module, which does ***NOT*** want to see a simple breaker point type switch but instead wants this "weird" signal you've described, using the falling edge as the trigger to generate the spark. It really does sound as though a simple resistor network might be fine, depending on the Bosch input requirements (unspecified, so far.)

Answer (score 0):

With the switched ground, probably the easiest way is to use an opto-isolator.

R3 and R4 generate a 1V low level when the transistor is off, and R2 pulls the output up to 3V when the optoisolator is on.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fF6CWR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks but I only have one power source, meaning I would use the same 12V for both sides, then I guess the hole idea with opto is gone ? I think I will use a simple voltage divider.

Comment: Use a 5V LDO / regulator to generate the 5V.  You can use a common ground with the opto-isolator without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Like this one, I have on big currents running so I guess this should work  : [image]

Comment: This will invert your PWM signal causing issues with the duty cycle.

Comment: It will ? I have a constant supply of 12V, when the SW is open I will have 3V. When the SW is closed I will have 1V (really 0,95V with the R choosen). As mentioned I am no big electrician, actually not at all :-) - But I think i will work. Please let me know what I am missing. Thanks

Comment: You might want to consider different resistor values, depending on the need for your Bosch input (it may require a lower impedance source.) For example, \$R_1=8.1\textrm{k}\Omega\$, \$R_2=2.7\textrm{k}\Omega\$, and \$R_3+R_4=1\textrm{k}\Omega\$. (You could round \$R_1\$ up to \$8.2\textrm{k}\Omega\$ to match a standard value.) That is, if the Bosch requires a lower impedance input source. We just don't know what it needs, though.

Comment: Hi Dean Now I see, you are right - the signal will be inverted. Need the 3 V then the SW1 is closed and the 1V when closed. I will try to build your circuit -That is working I can see :-)